# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT for one website on multiple computers

Tags: ping, connection-timeout

I have internet service via CenturyLink DSL. I am getting an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error when I try to access a particular website (198.58.101.168) from any computer on my network.

Details:

- I have tried to open the site on computers running Windows 10, macOS
  High Sierra, and iOS 11.0.3 that are connected to the internet via my CenturyLink modem. They all time out.
- I have tried using computers that are connected to the modem using both WiFi and Ethernet.
- I *can* visit this site this site using my AT&T iPhone when it is not connected to the CenturyLink network.
- This problem has existed for more than a week.

Given the above, it certainly seems like it is a problem with CenturyLink.

- I have restarted the modem (CenturyLink C1100Z).
- I asked the website host if they are receiving reports of any problems. They aren't, and they get thousands of page views each day.
- I ran "ipconfig /flushdns" on the Windows 10 computer (but again, this happens to Macs on this network, too).
- I am not having problems accessing other sites.
- The time-out problem also happens when I use the domain name rather than the IP address.
- I don't know of anything changing on my end (e.g., a modem setting).

Testing:

- When I ping the domain name or IP address on a Windows 10 computer (connected with Ethernet), ping reports "Request timed out" four times.
- When I tracert the IP address, it gets through 10 servers and then times out:

.

```
1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  modem.Home [192.168.0.1]
2    16 ms    16 ms    16 ms  207-108-176-15.slkc.qwest.net [207.108.176.15]
3    16 ms    16 ms    15 ms  slcy-agw1.inet.qwest.net [207.108.177.113]
4    25 ms    25 ms    25 ms  dvr-brdr-02.inet.qwest.net [67.14.24.14]
5    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  63-235-41-190.dia.static.qwest.net [63.235.41.190]
6    47 ms    47 ms    48 ms  be3035.ccr21.mci01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.5.90]
7    47 ms    48 ms    47 ms  be2432.ccr31.dfw01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.3.133]
8    47 ms    47 ms    47 ms  be2763.ccr41.dfw03.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.28.74]
9    48 ms    64 ms    47 ms  204.68.252.98
10   48 ms    48 ms    48 ms  45.79.12.1
11   *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I contacted CenturyLink and the support rep was clueless. He mostly offered solutions related to a Windows computer and failed to understand that this happens to any computer on my network.

I'm stumped...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my IP was being blocked (despite the host saying it wasn't). I discovered this by changing my static IP address.